# How to save Cytoscape network as flat JSON?

Tags: json, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

**How can I save a Cytoscape network as a flat JSON file?**

The `cytoscape.js` examples at [cytoscape.org](https://js.cytoscape.org/) typically store the underlying network data as a flat `data.json` file (e.g. [colas-graph](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/colajs-graph), see also https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

This is in contrast to the grouped or keyed format obtained when saving a graph as a Cytoscape JSON file (in Cytoscape: `file > Export > Network to File > Cytoscape JSON (*.cyjs))`.

**Note:** the [documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.json) indicates that I can use `cy.json()` to export a JSON representation of the graph, but I am unsure how to call this command (I am relatively new to javascript).

Comment: Developers usually name what you get with cytoscape.js constructor `var cy = cytoscape({ ... });` as `cy`. Just call `cy.json()`

Comment: I hope you are not confused between [cytoscape js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) and [cytocscape](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/saving-results/#/) documentation. In cytoscape js you can directly call cy.json() for the JSON, where cy is the cytoscape object

Comment: Thanks for your comments @canbax and @Abhi. I may have been confused between `Cytoscape` and `cytoscape.js`--they seem to be more independent than I thought. In short, use cytoscape.js and cy.json ()to save network data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the cytoscape object .json() for taking a json object and then download it as you like

here there is an example. I think StackOverflow is blocking downloading file but if you copy and paste this code it should be work

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));


  cy.ready(function() {
  const json = cy.json(); // take json from cytoscape
  // download json as you want
    const data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:' + data;
    a.download = 'data.json';
    a.innerHTML = 'download JSON';

    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(a);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  

</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
  <div id="container" style="position:absolute;top:10;left:10;z-index:1"></div>
</body>
```